# js найти значение и вернуть ключ

Tags: javascript, массивы

имеется массив содержащий массивы
var arr = {spb:[78,98,178,198], msk:[77, 97, 99, 177]};
как произвести в нем поиск по значениям и вернуть ключ?
если это в корне не верная идея, можно по другому.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пройти по объекту обычным циклом `for( key in object )`. Демо:

```js
let obj = {
  bubu: 555,
  moo: 77,
};

for( let key in obj ){
  console.log( "Ключ → ", key );
  console.log( "Значение → ", obj[key] );
  console.log( "=".repeat(20) );
}
```

```js
let obj = {
  spb: [78, 98, 178, 198],
  msk: [77, 97, 99, 177],
};

function findCity(obj, num){
  for( let key in obj ){
    if( obj[key].includes(num) ) return key;
    // return прямо посреди цикла прервет выполнение кода, если число совпадет.
  }
  return null;
}

console.log( findCity(obj, 198) ); // spb
console.log( findCity(obj, 177) ); // msk
console.log( findCity(obj, 175) ); // null
```